# UITextField - want to show last character entered in full textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I am creating an iphone app, and I am using a UITextField. In my textfield, if the user fills the textfield, I would still like the user to see what they are text. I am not using the keyboard to fill the textfield - the values are getting filled in from buttons on a calculator. It there a way to make the textfield show the most recently entered values as it normally would with the keyboard?

Thanks.

Here is the code that populates the textfield:

```
- (IBAction)number:(id)sender {
NSString *entry = [sender currentTitle];

NSLog(@"%@", entry);

if(justOpenedCalculator){
    total.text = @"";
    total.text = [total.text stringByAppendingString:entry];
    addFirstValueToDiscount = YES;

}else{
    total.text = [total.text stringByAppendingString:entry];
    addFirstValueToDiscount = YES;
}
justOpenedCalculator = NO;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you probably want to show us the code for the buttons that you're using to populate the textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you could not do it with the `textField`. Just go over the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods in the Apple Documentation, and implement it. Here is the [LINK](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) !. You need to implement that and instead of doing a `justOpenedCalculator` you could utilize the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method, and other `delegate` methods for your functions.

Make sure that you do a `yourTextField.inputView = yourCustomKeyboard`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField ...
```

And just assign the value to your textfield.